# Is it possible to change the background image of a button when you click it? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Is it possible to change the background image of a button when you click it? I'm using C# on Windows Forms Application.

Comment: It is, have you even tried searching?

Comment: Please use Google first, you will find tons of information about that..

Comment: Seek in the button events, i think something will be possible using the onclick and onrelease event, if not? Just create a new custom button.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Just set the `BackgroundImage` property of the button on it's click event.

Comment: Thanks you so much! 
But the image on the button is not stretched. Do you have any idea how to stretch the image on the button?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use some time to read through the properteies etc. of an object, just use intellisens of find the API for more details. BackgroundImageLayout is the property to look for at the moment..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
button1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("ImageFilepath");
button1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

Answer (score -1):

***background-size*** property of CSS3 should work for you i.e.,
*background-size:cover* or *background-size:100%*

Comment: it is windows forms app. not a web app.